# Alarm notification in hive/hadoop

Tags: hadoop, hive

I have been using apache hive for a while. And I want to know if there is a way of setting alarms in hive, ie., I want to know if I can run a shell script or send an email if there is a job failure. My hive jobs generally take a couple of hours and I want to get an immediate notification if it failed so that I can take an action immediately if my job failed. Or atleast please tell me if I can setup similar alarms in hadoop?

Answer (score 0):

When you call a hive script from Unix/Linux box, you use hive -(hyphen) and then your hive sql or hadoop thru unix script. So you execute your hive script or hadoop script from Unix/lInux box. So a shell script, which you need to use with mail or mailx is enough to alert you.

Cheers,
Raja
Available to help you in Teradata forum too
(ktraj1@gmail.com)